# Google Maps static image api used in dialogflow basic card gives problem, what to do?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have in a basic card an image with a Google Maps Static Image Api url (shortened via Firebase Dynamic Links Shorten Api, which produces links like this https://example.page.link/UVWXYZuvwxyz12345).
This used to worked without any problems, but since a few months/weeks this does not work on the Google Assistant at least on smart phones anymore, I only get a grey rectangle instead.
It works however in the Action on Google Emulator without any problems. The link shortening is not the problem because when I shorten a link to an arbitrary image on the internet the image is displayed without problems.
The image is 192px high as required in the docs.

Has anybody got this working in the last weeks? Any idea what changed?

Here is an example of such an unshortened google maps static image api url (please replace the YYY at the end with your own google maps key):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=330x192&markers=color:0xa10068%7Clabel:1%7C52.417908,9.6392955&markers=color:0x005eb8%7Clabel:3%7C52.42109,9.72186&markers=color:0x005eb8%7Clabel:5%7C52.4058059,9.7129063&markers=color:0x005eb8%7Clabel:7%7C52.42667,9.71606&markers=color:0x005eb8%7Clabel:8%7C52.32266,9.82017&markers=color:0x005eb8%7Clabel:9%7C52.3977616,9.7691778&path=color:green%7C52.417908,9.6392955%7C52.417908,9.6392955%7C52.42109,9.72186&path=color:green%7C52.4058059,9.7129063%7C52.42667,9.71606&path=color:green%7C52.32266,9.82017%7C52.3977616,9.7691778&path=color:green&maptype=roadmap&style=saturation:-30%7Clightness:30&style=feature:poi%7Cvisibility:off&style=feature:transit.station%7Cvisibility:off&key=YYY
```

Comment: Can you update your question to give an example of the URL being used?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I added an example, unfortunatly I can't provide an out-of-the-box-working link as you need a Google Maps api key for Google Maps Static Image Api

Comment: Are you using that link, or the short link? (Is it possible to see what the short link might look like? Possibly change a random character so it isn't a valid one?)

Comment: No, of course I use a shortened link as this is too long for dialogflow. As I wrote, I use firebase dynamic links shorten api, cf https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener which produces links like this https://example.page.link/UVWXYZuvwxyz12345 .